# How to explain light traveling two distances in the same frame of reference?

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, speed-of-light, time-dilation

Suppose I have a "moving" frame of reference where I send a light beam from point A to two equidistant points B and C (equidistant in the moving frame of reference). From a "stationary" frame of reference, A to B and A to C are different distances because they have different diagonal components. But the stationary observer still sees light travel from A to B and A to C at the same time. How is it possible given constant speed of light?

Just started learning about time dilation. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I would advise against "learning about time dilation".  It does not work, and this forum is ongoing testament to that.  You need to learn about the Lorentz Transform and the Spacetime interval, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacetime, and Spacetime diagrams: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacetime_diagram.  I can tell even without you giving a diagram that you will not be able to get an answer to your question, because you are describing "different diagonal components".  This means you have two space dimensions, as well as one time dimension, and this is not even taught at "beginner level".

Comment: @m4r35n357 that's a weird take. Time dilation definitely works, it's literally a part of the lorentz transform.

Comment: I know that ;)  But is is not a good starting place, people assume that when they understand gamma they can "do SR".  The sooner you can go from the Lorentz Transform, to the invariant interval, breeze through the "terrible twins" and get on to doppler, aberration, and so on , the better.  Time dilation on it own, but even more combined (?) with length contraction, is a nightmare source of bad questions on this site, especially when the posters are fooled in to thinking that any of this is "what they see".  I am thinking out loud now, but do you at least understand where I am coming from?

Answer (score 1):

From the moving observer's point of view, the light hits B and C at the same time.

From the stationary observer's point of view, the light does not reach B and C at the same time.

That's all there is to it.